# .htaccess file not working on my project

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am newbie on PHP and I am trying create a .htaccess file for my web.
I have follow this link :

[mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting/) **changed** my C:\xampp\apache\conf\ **httpd.conf** file

This is my **.htaccess** file and save under **test** folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule localhost/admin/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ localhost/test/application/admin/add_department.php?action=edit&page=$1
RewriteRule localhost/admin/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ localhost/test/application/admin/add_department.php?action=edit&page=$1
```

This is my **original url**:
localhost/test/application/admin/add_department.php?action=edit&department_id=11

I hope it **became to**:
localhost/admin/add_department/11

But its not working, the url bar still showing my **original url**.
Any information you need it please let me know, thanks~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match `localhost` using `RewriteRule`.

**Also you should place .htaccess a level above `test/` folder which is you website root.**

Have you rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(admin)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ test/application/$1/$2.php?action=edit&page=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also note use `/?$` for optional trailing slash. This will eliminate the need to have to 2 rules.

This will let you use `localhost/admin/add_department/11` URL in browser.

Comment: Hi,this is my file directory: **htdocs/test/**.
I had place my **.htaccess** under **htdocs** .
But when I use `localhost/admin/add_department/11` URL in browser, the page show **Object not found!**
Did i missed anything?

Comment: yes,`http://localhost/test/application/admin/add_department.php?action=edit&departme‌​nt_id=11` URL is work fine,

and i have updated my **C:\xampp\htdocs\.htaccess** file became 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(admin)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ test/application/$1/$2.php?action=edit&department_id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: Hi, I m facing a problem that is when **url bar** is `http://localhost/admin/add_department/11` then I clicked a button which  under a menu bar and will direct to **general_setting.php** but the **url will be** `http://localhost/admin/add_department/general_setting` and its is **not working**, i know when i use this method  **../general_setting** will work. But the problem is **my menu bar** have consists of other buttons, if i use **../** for all, when the url is `http://localhost/admin/general_setting` then I clicked another button will became `http://localhost/dashboard`